# Проверка на десятичную систему

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой, проверки числа на десятичную систему.

Допустим передают число 042 для редактирования 42 записи, вместо этого php отдаёт 34. Методом гугления не нашёл ничего(может запрос не правильно формулировал) что бы проверить на систему числа(2, 8, 10, 16).

Мой костыль проверка даёт эффект не всегда, только когда параметр string

```
if (substr($param[0], 0, 1) == 0 || substr($param[0], 0, 2) == "0x" || substr($param[0], 0, 2) == "0b") Throw new Exception($message);
```

Есть какой то встроенный метод проверки системы числа? Или кто то уже сталкивался и есть решение

Comment: Ведущий ноль - признак восьмеричного числа. *Есть какой то встроенный метод проверки системы числа?* Мало того что нет - вообще сомнительно, что такой существует. Число 111 валидно в любой системе счисления.

Comment: @Akina Я же написал в вопросе

Comment: @Akina иногда параметр приходит в стринге тогда можно проверить на ведущий ноль

Comment: Заминусовали беднягу :D Возможно вам просто надо проверять, чтобы в строке были только числа) можно регуляркой обычной пройтись даже.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что не для строк не существует никаких систем счислений:

```
var_dump([
    100,
    0100,
    0x100,
    0b100
]); // [100, 64, 256, 4]
```

Это просто способ указать литерал в другой системе счисления, такая форма абсолютно неотличима от своего значения в десятичном виде:

```
var_dump([
    0100 === 64,
    0x100 === 256,
    0b100 === 4
]); // [true, true, true]
```

Не имеет смысла пытаться отличить 042 от 34. Оба литерала обозначают одно и то же число. Если в итоге получается не то, что клиентский код имел в виду - виноват клиентский код.

Comment: Я же указал в вопросе, вы мне показываете что я уже знаю.

Comment: `Есть какой то встроенный метод проверки системы числа?` Нет, нет и не может быть.

Comment: Нашёл. Правда не встроеный. И это имеет смысл что бы защититься от пользователя

Comment: Вы нашли нечто иное =)

Answer (score -3):

Пока все настаивали и говорили что нельзя такого сделать и ставили минусы к вопросу я нашёл ответ на английском стаке. Надеюсь в дальнейшем поможет кому либо

```
function is_decimal( $val )
{
    return is_numeric( $val ) && floor( $val ) != $val;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772603/check-if-number-is-decimal

Спасибо всем кто говорил что такого нельзя сделать и не имеет смысла

Comment: Это неверное решение: https://3v4l.org/Sdvso Либо решение не той задачи, что вы указали в вопросе

Comment: Это проверка на то, что в числе есть точка, непонятно как вы решили ей задачу из вашего топика. Вообще вы бы лучше описали задачу, мне кажется ваши проблемы решаются приведением строки с указанием основания [простым intval](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php): $result = intval("042", 10);

Comment: @AlexKrass да тут согласен, я проверил на 077 и на 0b10 выдало false, обрадовался. Сейчас сижу ищу материал. Мне надо проверить что число что получил в параметре было в десятичной системе, так как столкнулся с проблемой получения json от пользователя в котором он правит материал с номером 042 а исправил в итоге материал с номером 34

Comment: @Walfter я бы занялся в таком случае унификацией приложения: отдавал бы пользователю валидный string, принимал бы от пользователя только приведенный по правилам string. Если на клиенте есть JS, то проверил бы, что он обрабатывает данные актуально. Похоже на баг в каком-то месте, который хорошо бы выловить, а не править костылем.

Comment: Так же в любом случае к вам приходит строка в исходном виде, а не число т.к. другого механизма обмена насколько я помню нет. Значит либо она уже пришла с ошибкой, либо ее неправильно привели где-то выше по коду. Возможно приходящий JSON имеет смысл перед парсингом проверить заранее.

Comment: @AlexKrass Как мне проверить файл который отправляет пользователь(json), который он сделал сам, но случайно указал ноль перед номером материала `{"material": 042, ***}`

Comment: @Walfter вариант в лоб - выбрать все числа через regexp и обрезать ведущий 0 при его наличии, далее заменить их все через replace на новые варианты. И уже только потом отдавать парсеру json. Если посидеть и подумать, возможно найдется более простое решение.

Comment: Решать эту проблему нужно там, где этот JSON собирается. Для сервера должно быть всё равно - ему сказали, что материал = 34 - он его и "правит".

Comment: @vp_arth от таких пользователей в любом случае надо защитится. JSON сборка от меня не зависит, только сервер

Comment: Защищаться нужно не от этого. Если пользователь авторизован менять материал №34 - значит всё ок. С другой стороны, я понимаю, что мы живём не в идеальном мире и можно пробовать административные проблемы решать костылями. В стандарте json 042 также равен 34.

Comment: @vp_arth да тоже равен 34 но, тем не менее пользователь доказывает что отправлял на 42 а исправил 34. Пересмотр файлов показал что он отправил в 042 что и равно 34. Начали боятся что это повторится. И вот решаю сижу.... А у клиента пока что нельзя ничего поменять(по регламенту раз в полгода они могут принимать обновления и то не от меня), и не понятно кто писал сборщик(что бы сообщить о данном инциденте). Сейчас пока делаю с регуляркой как предложил Alex Krass